# How to get earnings through Webhook

Tags: uber-api

Webhook send me this parameters: event_id, event_time, event_type, meta.user_id, meta.resource_id, meta.status, resource_href.
I need to know driver earnings, which complete trip with status "complete". 
How can i get this information?

Answer (score 2):

You would need access to the payments Driver API endpoint for that information. Documentation for that endpoint is here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-payments-get which includes a link for application. To set expectations, I believe it is in very limited access currently.